# Pandas: Adding new columns total_count, for babynames and national names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported two datasets in my notebook. One which consists of the names that were given to baby's for each state in each year (and the number, [count] of it). The other one consists of the total number of people in the U.S with that name with that specific name. (see added images).

The problem here is that I appended the two datasets, so that they became one dataset, since merging and concat didn't work.

I want to create a column 'Totalcount' next to all the columns where the state is also mentioned (not NAN), so that I can compare the babynames to the national count of that specific name for each state.

For example: in 1934, 4 baby's have been named 'Anna' in Texas. The number of people named 'Anna' in the U.S were 14000 in 1934. The number of 'totalcount' should be 14000 then. This number should be 14000 for next to the other states as well. 
So: 5 baby's have been named 'Anna' in California, and total count would still be 14000. I have tried many things but I can't figure it out.

[The dataset, above: the national count of names in each year, but without the States. Under: The count of certain babynames which are given in each state, I appended these two datasets since merging or concat didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4wTQ.jpg)

example states dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['AF',1910.0, 'F', 'Mary', 14.0], ['TX',1910.0, 'M' , 'Lex', 15.0], ['CA',1920.0,'M','Tom', 14.0]], columns=['State', 'Sex','Year','Name','Count'])
```

example national dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Anna','F', 2402,1910], ['Ben','M',5044,1912], ['Simon','M',39203,1910]], columns=['Name', 'Sex','Count','Year'])
df2
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think I understand your question in general, but without more information, it's hard to answer...

Comment: Just to be sure, you want total count of names irrespective of the years right?

Comment: First - can you create a minimal example that reproduces your problem? Like a `pd.DataFrame` with even only 2 or 3 rows, posted as code (or as data, but code is best) and not as image

Comment: With such an example, we could also understand what doesn't work in your joining process.

Comment: In my opinion, merging should have been the way to go: 
` pd.merge(left=df, right=df2, on='Name')`. Maybe you can elaborate why it did not work for you.

Comment: No, I want the total count of names like 'Anna' in the specific year that is in the States dataset (where number of babynames given in each state is) The year does matter. So in 1993, 4 baby's have been given the name 'Anna' in TX (texas), while there were 14000 people named 'Anna' in 1993. The 14000 'Anna's, should be in the total_count colomn, (since there were  14000 Anna's in 1993). This should work for all the other states as well. @ YOLO

Comment: As a new contributor, you really should read [ask]. You are supposed to give a [mcve], not a link to an non copy-pastable image. An when it comes to pandas please read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @JuliaKraus The code you mentioned will give a memory error, already tried it.

Comment: I've added example dataframes so that it becomes a bit clearer :)

Comment: You might want to try reading in the two dataframes using `low_memory = True` parameter in `pd.read_csv` and then merging again. See https://www.kaggle.com/kunalkotian/easily-load-train-csv-w-o-crash-save-feather-file

Comment: @Julia K this worked! Thank you so much!!  :D